# VSCode v1.62.2 on M1 11.6 not starting debugger on pre-saved workspaces

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger, apple-m1, javascript-debugger

After **November's Recovery Update 2**, VSCode fails to start debugging on pre-saved workspaces.

It is *MacOS* specific. Don't know if it is *M1* specific.

If I open the workspace's folders one by one and manually add them to a new workspace, debugger starts fine.

As soon as I save the workspace to a file, that's when debugger cannot start.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix for anyone with the same problem: Open up your terminal and run

```
code /path/to/workspaceFile
```

Maybe is a permissions issue with the new update?

The problem is present if I do a fresh install of the VSCode.app